# Find an equation for the sphere centered at $(1,0,1)$ and tangent to the plane $x+y-z=1$

Tags: calculus

i know the equation of a sphere tangent to a plane is $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 = r^2$ but I'm having trouble setting up this problem

Comment: That's the equation for a sphere centered at the point $(a, b, c)$, not one tangent to some particular plane. I think perhaps more review is in order. A question to ponder: suppose we call $S$ the sphere you're looking for. Must $S$ contain a point of the plane?

Answer (score 2):

The normal vector to your plane is  $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$. So consider the line,$\textbf{L}$ given by $$\textbf{L}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$
This line originates from the centre of your sphere. So you can find the point of intersection with the plane by solving for $\lambda$. Then $r$ is simply the distance from the centre of your sphere to that point.

Comment: yes but when you solve for lambda and plug it back in to get the radius, does it give you your radius as a vector or the magnitude of the radius

Comment: the vector from the centre of the sphere to the point of intersection is $\lambda (1,1,-1)$ so the radius is simply, $r= | \lambda | \sqrt{3} $